# My Mom Doesn't Allow Any Screen Time At All!

Tags: parents, screen-time, rules, mother

Recently, my mom changed my entire lifestyle completely in just a week. Exercising for one hour, avoiding snacks. I'm fine with the first two, but the last one is just cruel. I'm not allowed any screen time at all unless it's for school(or something educational). Even before this new rule was placed, I almost never watched for more than three hours. I understand that she's doing this bcause she loves me and all, but she wouldn't even allow thirty minutes! I feel a lot of stress and watching a bit always helps me ease it a little. This rule really took a toll on my brother and sister. How can I convince my mom to loosen this rule?

Comment: Could you add more context? How old are you? What's your cultural background? Has your mother stated any reasons for this new rule? Is this meant only for TV/Netflix/YouTube or even for using a PC creatively (programming, producing music etc.)?

Comment: @JanNiklasFingerle, I'm 13, my cultural background is Asian. My mom made this new rule because she believes it wastes time, and this is meant for basically using YouTube, Netflix, and other things for video entertainment.

Answer (score 2):

I can't give you a real solution, because much depends on the dynamics between you and your mom. So, these are some hints that *might* help you when talking to your mom.

- Try to talk to you mom in a calm setting. Ask her when she has time to discuss this matter.
- Let her explain in depth, why she thinks, screen time is bad at all.
- Explain to her, what positive effects you experience with your use of screen time.
- Try to achieve a compromise. A maximum number of hours a day? Only certain days? Only after having done something that your mom considers useful?
- *If* you can talk on that level with your mom, mention that learning to use TV/computer etc. in a responsible way has as a prerequisite to be able to use it at all. Discuss what "responsible" would mean.
- If some of this is due to generational divide ("your mother just doesn't understand you"), you could discuss this in the context of what problems your mom had with her mother.

All this can only help, if your mother sees you as someone who can grow into being responsible for themselves, and is willing to go that step. I don't know you, I don't know your mother, so it's up to you to decide if there's anything in here that may help you.